# WSO2 ESB TCP/UDP Axis2 server (case study)

Tags: tcp, udp, apache-axis, wso2-esb

I have been studying WSO2 ESB for this particular case:
We got some remote devices that monitor various types of data (temperature, wind, warnings, alarms, panic, Etc.) this devices send data packages to a server by UDP and TCP mostly in binary format (start bit, protocol, values, time, stop bit).

I know that WSO2 ESB can support TCP and UDP Transport by an axis2 server, however all the examples I have found need the data to be in SOAP format (or XML like). 
Is there any way to config the Axis2 server to receive the raw packages?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this can be achieved by configuring message builders and formatters in the axis2.xml.
Apache Axis2, which is the base for Apache Synpase's SOAP processing, helps users to add their custom message formats through Builders and Formatters.

A Builder accepts a binary data stream and creates an XML message, and a Formatter accepts a XML message and converts it to bytes. 
Add the following message builders and formatters to the corresponding sections in conf/axis2.xml (for both Apache Synapse and WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus).

```
<messageBuilder contentType="text/html"
class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
<messageFormatter contentType="text/html"
class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
```

The above example shows how to enable Binary Relay for text/html content type. 
You need to repeat the above pair of configurations for each content type you want to be handled at the byte level.

For more information on Setting up Binary-Relay please refer this [documentation](http://wso2.com/library/articles/binary-relay-efficient-way-pass-both-xml-non-xml-content-through-apache-synapse/).

Hope this information will help you.